# How can I use scipy.integrate.solve_ivp() to solve an ODE in an interactive simulation?

Tags: python, scipy, simulation, ode

I have implemented a simple simulation on a uniform circular motion using the low level API `scipy.integrate.RK45()` like the following.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = np.array([1, 0], 'float')
v = np.array([0, 1], 'float')
dt = 0.1

def motion_eq(t, y):
    r, v = y[0:2], y[2:4]
    return np.hstack([v, -r])
motion_solver = scipy.integrate.RK45(motion_eq, 0, np.hstack([r, v]),
    t_bound = np.inf, first_step = dt, max_step = dt)

particle, *_ = plt.plot(*r.T, 'o')
plt.gca().set_aspect(1)
plt.xlim([-2, 2])
plt.ylim([-2, 2])
def update():
    motion_solver.step()
    r = motion_solver.y[0:2]
    particle.set_data(*r.T)
    plt.draw()
timer = plt.gcf().canvas.new_timer(interval = 50)
timer.add_callback(update)
timer.start()

plt.show()
```

I tried at first the high level API `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp()`, but it seems it doesn't provide an interface to create an instance containing the state of the system and get states of the system iteratively.(I am calling this an interactive simulation, because you can pause, change the system state and resume, although it's not implemented in the sample code.)

Is this possible with the `solve_ivp()`? If it is not, am I doing right with the `RK45`, especially on specifying the `t_bound`, `first_step` and `max_step` options? I can find plenty of resources on solving for a given time interval on Internet, but I couldn't find one on solving like this.

Comment: The actual step size can become smaller than `dt`, even in the first step if the computation with `dt` is rejected due to a large error.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann, can you review my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not an expert on the numerical analysis, I'm answering my own question, because I have come to a conclusion after analyzing the `solve_ivp()` and `RK45` implementation and experimenting with APIs.

Firstly, the high level API `solve_ivp()` does not provide an interface to create an instance containing the state of the system and get states of the system iteratively. So, I should do like this even though it's inefficient.

```
dt = 0.1
t = 0
r = np.array([1, 0], 'float')
v = np.array([0, 1], 'float')

def motion_eq(t, y):
    r, v = y[0:2], y[2:4]
    return np.hstack([v, -r])

...
def update():
    global t, r, v
    sol = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(motion_eq, (t, t + dt), np.hstack([r, v]),
        t_eval = (t + dt,), method = 'RK45')
    t = sol.t[0]
    r, v = sol.y[0:2, 0], sol.y[2:4, 0]
    ...
...
```

Secondly, the low level API `RK45` provides the interface to create an instance containing the state of the system(the `RK45()` initializer) and get states of the system iteratively(the `step()` method), but it does not provide an interface to control the time step at each iteration. But if the desired time step is constant and small enough, you can control the time step in some degree via the `first_step` and `max_step` arguments of the `RK45()` initializer, like the example in the question.

This can be seen in [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.0/scipy/integrate/_ivp/rk.py#L153) and [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.0/scipy/integrate/_ivp/rk.py#L122). At the end of the `_step_impl()`, the `self.h_abs` gets larger then the previous value before the call. But at the start of the `_step_impl()` on the next call, it is limited to the `self.max_step`. But as Lutz Lehmann said, if the estimated error(the `error_norm`) is large, the `self.h_abs` at the next call will be smaller than the `self.max_step`. So in this case, it is required to loop and interpolate like the following.(The interpolation part is attributed to Lutz Lehmann.)

```
...
dt = 0.1
t = 0
...
motion_solver = scipy.integrate.RK45(motion_eq, 0, np.hstack([r, v]),
    t_bound = np.inf, first_step = dt, max_step = dt)
...
def update():
    global t
    t += dt
    while motion_solver.t < t:
        motion_solver.step()
    sol = motion_solver.dense_output()
    y = sol(t) # interpolation
    r, v = y[0:2], y[2:4]
    ...
...
```

Comment: If you want more precision, use the dense output to get the best state approximation at `t_next`, `sol=motion_solver.dense_output(); y_next=sol(t_next)`.

Comment: That looks good now. In a more general situation the velocities will be on a different scale than the position, so you would need individual absolute tolerances or some scaling between model and solver values.